# Querying image IRI from annotations in Protege

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege

I currently have an ontology in which an individual of a class has annotations like so :
[Individual Batanta with annotation property hasImage that contains an IRI that points to an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GbIc.png)

The annotations each have an IRI that points to an image stored on the web.

My question is, is it possible for me to do a SPARQL query for the IRI that points to the image that's shown in each annotation's thumbnails? I've tried the following query :

```
PREFIX foo:http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Tourism.owl/Touring#
select ?Regency ?Image 
    {?Regency foo:hasAttraction foo:Batanta. 
     ?Regency foo:hasImage ?Image}
```

No results came up.

Comment: if the result is empty, the query doesn't match the data. Did you check the URIs resp. the namespace for typos? Also, is there data that has as attraction Batanta and an image?

Comment: by the way, I assume that you just forgot the angle brackets here in the post for the prefix declaration, otherwise the query parser would fail anyways